# Listing Count per "Category" for IQueryable

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an mvc-page that lists categories, and I would like to have it to count the number of products per category. It's IQueryable.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Categories) { %>
.....
<td><%: item.CategoryName %></td>
<td><%: item.Products.Count() %></td>
```

It lists:
5
5

Instead of:
3
2

Any Ideas how I can "partition" it per category?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by category name and get sum of all the product counts per category.  See if this works for you.

```
var query = Model.Categories
                 .GroupBy(item => item.CategoryName)
                 .Select(g => new {
                             CategoryName = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Sum(item => item.Products.Count())
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

it is also possible with the LINQ syntax:

```
var query = from item in Model.Categories
            group item by item.CategoryName into g
            select new { CategoryName = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```